# Reset timer in Java

Tags: java, timer, reset

I have tried to reset the timer based on the current time after clicking a button, but it doesn't work.

```
private long startTime  = System.currentTimeMillis();
Timer timer  = new Timer(1000, this);
timer.start();

timer.stop();
long endTime    = System.currentTimeMillis();
long timeInMilliseconds = (endTime - startTime);

timer.reset();
```

Comment: What do you expect Timer.reset to do, and what is it doing?

Comment: You need to elaborate your question and comment the code snippet: when various parts of it are run, etc.

Comment: Atually I need to reset the time according to the most current system timer..but I got the solution now. I just need to place the startTime  = System.currentTimeMillis(); again in the button actionListener method.

Comment: None of the Timer classes that are part of the JDK have a reset() method, so we need more information to know what you're trying to do.

Comment: If you have a solution, add it to the answers here and mark it as accepted.

Comment: I'm baffled as to what you are attempting to do with Timer here, and what that has to do with the timeInMilliseconds business - they don't seem related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for my program. Thanks everyone.

```
   public class mainClass {
        private long startTime  = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Timer timer  = new Timer(1000, this);
        .....
    }

    public mainClass {
        timer.start();
    }

    //Everytime the button stop clicked, the time will stop and reset to the most current time of the system
    public actionPerformed () {
        timer.stop();
        long endTime    = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long timeInMilliseconds = (endTime - startTime);

        **startTime  = System.currentTimeMillis();** ACCEPTED
    }
```

Comment: For future reference, all Java classes (in your case, "mainClass") should start with a capital letters and you probably shouldn't use the word "class" in then name of a class.

Answer (score 6):

My magic crystal ball says you are using a javax.swing.Timer and that there is no reset() method, it is called restart().

But then it could be wrong, it would be nice if you were a bit more explicit about what you are doing ...

Comment: Actually what I need was to start the timer again to the current system time. But it solved now...I just need to place the startTime  = System.currentTimeMillis() again in ActionListener and not in main class.